# Update Node version while creating AWS lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a lambda function. When I push it using AWS amplify, I get the following error:

```
CREATE_FAILED      UpdateRolesWithIDPFunction AWS::Lambda::Function     


Wed Dec 29 2021 14:23:50 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) Resource handler returned 

message: 
"The runtime parameter of nodejs10.x is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs14.x) while creating or updating functions. 
(Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8eccb550-8523-44c4-b085-7d2804efb2bb, Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: ed50aa71-19fa-1349-6b6f-4d7724300293, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I am taking the reference of this video for creating:

[Build an Online Store Using AWS, React, and Stripe - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgwI22y_eFA&t=1791s)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Presumably you know you can no longer create node 10 functions, you need to change the version to a supported one.

Comment: AWS is only supports LTS node version.
Check this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtime-support-policy.html

Comment: make sure you also specify the runtime update to use at least node version >=12

Answer (score 0):

Amplify has its own dependency on node. Even if your function is not dependent on node 10, the amplify version you are using may be.